# How to pass variables through ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass variables from `post.php` to `addcomment.php` through the AJAX request. I have tried the code below but it does not seem to work. It reloads the page but nothing happens nor is data inserted in database

post.php

```
//variables to pass
$userid = $row['userid'];
$uid = $row['uid'];
$postid = $row['postid'];

<form method='post' name='form' action='' class='commentbox'>
<textarea name='content' id='content'></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' value='Comment' name='submit' class='comment_button'/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var userfrom = '<?php echo $uid ?>';
    var userto = '<?php echo $userid ?>';
    var postid = '<?php echo $postid ?>';

    $(function() {
        $(".comment_button").click(function() {
            var test = $("#content").val();
            var dataString = 'content='+ test;

            if (test == '') {
                alert("Please Enter Some Text");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addcomment.php",
                    data: {    
                        dataString: dataString, 
                        userfrom: userfrom, 
                        userto: userto,
                        postid: postid 
                    }
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $(".display").show(html);
                    }
                });
            } 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

addcomment.php

```
    if (isset($_POST['dataString'], $_POST['userto'], $_POST['userfrom'], $_POST['postid'])) {
        $userid = $_POST['userto'];
        $uid = $_POST['userfrom'];
        $postid = $_POST['postid'];
        $comment = $_POST['dataString'];
        $com = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment,userto, userfrom, post) VALUES (:comment, :userto, :userfrom, :post)");
        $com->execute(array(':comment'=>$comment,':userto'=>$userid,':userfrom'=>$uid,':post'=>$postid));
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information than 'it doesn't work'. Have you at least checked console for errors, or the network tab of the console to see the state of the request?

Comment: Also, note that you're missing a `,` after the object you provide to the `data` parameter

Comment: Please add also your html code (at least the one related to the form). It might be that you are not linking the callback to the right event. I would also advise you to use the "submit" event of the form instead that the "click" one.

Comment: Are there any errors showing?

Comment: FYI, this looks really insecure (easy to spoof) to send some user IDs to server from client side. I hope you are doing it only for comments, not for any other way to authenticate users

Comment: you need to prevent the form from submitting, google preventDefault()

Comment: @A.Wolff is there any better(secure) way to do that ?

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə The user sending comment authentification should be done only server side, using variable session or token.

Answer (score 2):

Create hidden fields for userid, uid and postid and assign the values. 
Get the values as **var userfrom = $("#uid").val();** in script (post.php). It will Work

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, just replace below code.

your page is reloaded because of add button type submit, for ajax event you need to set type button, Please check below code :

```
<?php 
//variables to pass
$userid = $row['userid'];
$uid = $row['uid'];
$postid = $row['postid'];
?>
<form method='post' name='form' action='' class='commentbox'>
<textarea name='content' id='content'></textarea><br />
<input type='button' value='Comment' name='submit' class='comment_button'/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    var userfrom = '<?php echo $uid ?>';
    var userto = '<?php echo $userid ?>';
    var postid = '<?php echo $postid ?>';

    $(function() {
        $(".comment_button").click(function() {
            var test = $("#content").val();
            var dataString = 'content='+ test;

            if (test == '') {
                alert("Please Enter Some Text");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "addcomment.php",
                    data: {    
                        dataString: dataString, 
                        userfrom: userfrom, 
                        userto: userto,
                        postid: postid 
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $(".display").show(html);
                    }
                });
            } 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```